Прямая ссылка на скачивание встроенного видео
Есть сайт, на котором в <iframe> встраивается видео. Через Network в инструментах разработчика ручками можно раскопать ссылку на скачивание видео. Только вот если в тайтле 500 серий, каждую вот так ручками скачивать будет как минимум очень долго. Хотелось бы написать софтину, которая бы по ссылке на тайтл скачивала бы сразу все серии из плейлиста.
Ни малейшего понятия не имею, как это можно было бы реализовать. В какую сторону копать?
Пример плейлиста: https://animejoy.ru/tv-serialy/4324-etot-zamechatelnyy-mir-3-sezon.html

ссылки есть непосредственно в разметке, в списке кнопок плеера с сериями.

@Grundy К сожалению, не во всех плейлистах доступны все плееры. Если это какой-нибудь Sibnet, то там так просто ссылку не выудить. В media идет http-запрос на этот URL: https://cvs120-2.sibnet.ru/35/63/13/3563134.mp4?st=o3GgjGiLFYNvxd_7aou98Q&e=1716446000&stor=21&noip=1
Есть ли какой-то способ по ссылке на плейлист получать прямые ссылки на скачивание всех серий?

что ты имеешь ввиду говоря "ссылка на плейлист". Плейлист сам из себя представляет список ссылок. Если у тебя нет списка ссылок - это не плейлист

@Grundy Наверное, я неправильно выражаюсь. Я плейлистом обозвал страницу тайтла.

Все зависит от страницы. На ней может быть список, может не быть, может быть на уровне плеера, может в разметке html. Раз там разное для разных плееров - то и общего подхода быть не может. Сначала определись для какого плеера хочешь решение - потом смотри как он работает - станет ясно как делать. Если нужно для любого плеера - делать то же самое - для каждого плеера.
